# mariadb on rds when creating a new procedure creates new user @ ip.ec2.host

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

We have a `mariadb` instance on rds that is being called from a bash script. Within the script we create a `procedure` that is deleted after the .sql script completes. The `mysql` user has been set up as `myUser`@`%` with custom privileges

```
delimiter |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myTmpProc |
CREATE PROCEDURE myTmpProc()
BEGIN
... --code goes here
-- Execute the stored procedure 
CALL myTmpProc() | 
-- Don't forget to drop the stored procedure when you're done! 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myTmpProc | 
DELIMITER ;
```

The create, run, delete part script runs as expected and completes.

However this process is creating a new user `myUser`@`x.x.x.x` of the ec2 instance running the script. This user does not have any privileges.

When we next run the script it runs as the new user and fails as that user has no privileges.

IS this expected behaviour to create a new user with the same User name but at the ec2 ip address when creating a new procedure?

How can we stop the user from being created?

Comment: I don't know of any way to _implicitly_ generate a user.  Check for `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` statements somewhere in the script _or_ before it.

Comment: @RickJames I experienced this on RDS/MySQL 5.6 at a former job.  One developer would periodically pop up with a new account username@his-private-ip in mysql.user.  He didn't have `GRANT OPTION` on his "real" account.  I don't remember whether I ever solved it at the time, but thinking about it now, I suspect it could be sketchy/questionable behavior related to  [`automatic_sp_privileges`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_automatic_sp_privileges).  Thoughts?

Comment: @artvanderlay will you try setting `automatic_sp_privileges` to `0` in the RDS parameter group for this DB instance and see if that addresses the issue?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - My thoughts are that no one turns off the flag.  And there there were some bugs in the feature -- see my 'Answer'.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot due to a time constraint we were not able to do the parameter change. But we did confirm Rick James note that adding the execute privilege stopped the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too big for a Comment) (from the changelogs)

----- 2018-10-26 MariaDB 5.5.62 & 2018-09-25 MariaDB 10.2.18 -- -- -----

Bug#27407480: AUTOMATIC_SP_PRIVILEGES REQUIRES NEED THE INSERT PRIVILEGES FOR MYSQL.USER TABLE

----- 2018-07-27 8.0.12 General Availability & 2018-07-27 5.7.23 General Availability & 2018-07-27 5.6.41 General Availability & 2018-07-27 5.5.61 General availability -- -- -----

With [automatic_sp_privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_automatic_sp_privileges) enabled, the [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) and [ALTER ROUTINE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter-routine) privileges were not correctly granted to routine creators. (Bug #27407480)

----- 2017-04-10 8.0.1 Development Milestone -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

When the [automatic_sp_privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_automatic_sp_privileges) system variable was enabled, it did not have the expected effect for anonymous users. (Bug #20266641)

----- 2015-04-08 5.7.7 Release Candidate -- Bugs Fixed -- Replication -----
----- 2015-04-06 5.6.24 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- Replication -----

When the [automatic_sp_privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_automatic_sp_privileges) variable is set, the server automatically grants the [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) and [ALTER ROUTINE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter-routine) privileges to the creator of a stored routine, if the user does not already have these privileges. When a privileged user creates a procedure with DEFINER as a non privileged user on a master, the current user is considered to be a privileged user and the mysql.procs_priv table is not updated. When such a statement was replicated to slave, the non-privileged DEFINER was considered as the current user on the slave and privileges were being allocated. This caused a difference in the privileges that were being allocated on the master and the slave. The fix ensures that creater of the stored routine is added to the binary log, and the slave now checks first if the user exists before granting privileges. To maintain compatibility with previous versions, the DEFINER is used when the INVOKER is not available. As part of this fix, anonymous users can be used to replicate from master to slave. (Bug #20049894)

----- not yet released 5.0.8 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

The granting and revocation of privileges on a stored routine was performed when running the server with [--skip-grant-tables](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) even after the statement SET @@GLOBAL.automatic_sp_privileges = 1; was executed. (Bug #9993)

Comment: Thanks for confirming Rick. We came to the same conclusion that the `%` user did not have `EXECUTE` privilege and as a result the 2nd user was being created.